# Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas - Truffle

Tags: truffle, truffle-test

I'm facing some issue with test cases, I wrote some simple function in my smart contract as following:

```
function Create ( 
    bytes32 _a,
    address _b,
    string _c,
    address[] _d,
    uint256[] _e,

) public pure returns(bool){
    return true;
}
```

And here is the test case:

```
describe("Unit Test For Create Method", () => {
    it("first test case", async () => {
        const estimateGas = await Instance.Create.estimateGas(a, b, c, d, e);
        console.log(estimateGas);            
    });
});
```

while running test case, it's giving an error `Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas`

If I remove any single parameter, it starts working..
so, I assume there is an issue with number of arguments..any help?

Edit:
I have defined variable globally:

```
contract('Unit Test for smart contract', function(){
    let a = "XVXIJLO-9XNQ-ZQWF-OLAF-E14L09FHZALQ",
        b = web3.eth.accounts[1],
        c = "fileHash",
        d = ['s1','s2'],
        e = [0,1,2],
        Instance;

        // test case here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging deeply, I found the exact cause of that error.

I was passing 36 bytes to the `_a` variable, wheres actual `_a` defined with `bytes32` datatype.

In order to solve this issue, modified id to 32 bytes.

Or

use web3 js:

```
id = web3.sha3("XVXIJLO-9XNQ-ZQWF-OLAF-E14L09FHZALQ");
```

Hope this will help to others!